# How to create a responsive div with img in it?

Tags: css, responsive-design

i would like to create a responsive div(`box1`) which should fit to its content size automatically and also i have a restriction for that content which should not exceed certain value(width and height) of `box1` here i give `600x300`.

Here is the code and example

```
 .box1
    {
       width:auto;
       height:auto;
       background-color:chocolate;
       margin-left:auto;
       margin-right:auto;
       max-width: 600px;
       max-height:300px;
       padding:5px;

    }
```

I used `max-width :600px;` and `max-height:300px;` so the content inside it won't exceed above `box1` according to my belief.

```
.box1 img
    {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
```

Here image inside `box1` won't exceed `box1` width and height.

Now
1) if the image is higher than `box1` width and height of `600x300px` let say `750x750px` in this case image should fit in `box1` with `600x300px`

2) if the image is lesser than `600x300px`  let say `200x150px` then the `box1` should adjust automatically to the image size.

How this can be achieved? what wrong in my code to this concept? can anybody help?

Comment: Just use background images in the divs instead?

Comment: In your examples, your images have either a square or landscape aspect ratio.  Do you anticipate having images with portrait aspect ratios (height>width)?

Comment: @ Marc Audet i'm not concerning any aspect ratio.all i like to do is fit that image inside **box1**.

Comment: Excellent read about this topic: http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using CSS

Consider the following HTML, I am including four images of various aspect ratios to illustrate that this works.  The `.wrap` element is to show you you might center the image within its parent block.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box1">
        <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/500/500">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box1">
        <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/800/200">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box1">
        <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/200/800">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box1">
        <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/200/200">
    </div>
</div>
```

The trick is to set `display: inline-block` for `.box1`, which will force it to shrink to fit the content subject to the max-width and max-height constraints.

```css
.box1 {
    width:auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 300px;
    background-color:chocolate;
    padding:5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

To get the image to scale correctly, simply inherit the max-width and max-height values:

```css
.box1 img {
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: inherit;
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

Use `vertical-align: top` to get rid of any white space near the image tag.

Finally, since `.box1` is an inline-block, you can center it within its parent container using `text-align: center`:

```css
.wrap {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    margin: 1.00em 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The demo fiddle is at:  http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/hpbdC/

Comment: Just want to know two things.How long have you been doing designing and which book would you prefer to learn css in depth? @Marc Audet

Comment: @raj I have been working with HTML/CSS for about 12 years, general programming for over 30 years, and in the web design/development business for 10 years.  I have read most of the books by Eric Meyer on CSS (CSS: Definitive Guide + Eric Meyer on CSS), also recommend books by Dan Cederholm (Bulletproof Web Design + Handcrafted CSS).

Answer (score 2):

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

should work (I assume you want keep aspect ratio)

Answer (score 1):

By default box1 is treated as a display: block element. If you change that display type to an inline-block (ex: display: inline-block) it would be treated as an adjustable item.

Do keep in mind that you are setting the max height of the box to 300px. Therefore, the image's max-height is three hundred. In the case of a 750px by 750px image, it will be resized to a 300px by 300px image (and so will the box).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the wrapping div? You can achieve this by only styling the image: http://jsfiddle.net/Rv7JG/1/

```
img {
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    background: chocolate;
}
```

Comment: The image is getting distorted a bit, but the dog does not seem to mind!

Comment: It is a trickier problem than it appears, but I still like the dog!

Comment: @Marc Audet thank my stackoverflow friend.First i would like to solve this problem then i will come back to the quality of the image problem. i would like to solve problems step by step.

Comment: @dwreck08 your idea is nice. `img {width:auto;}` will solve the image distortion problem?

Comment: @raj The problem is the aspect ratio for that particular image. If you set the max-width and max-height to ratio that doesn't go with the image, it will get distorted when it reaches the max for each.  You can see if I set it to a max of 400x300px it looks correct: http://jsfiddle.net/Rv7JG/2/

Comment: @dwreck08 thanks for your time.You shown fiddle with body tag but in my case its `box1`.i tested it in my browser the image getting correct with your idea but the `box1` width showing fully till the screen ends.why it happens?

Comment: @raj I would just lose the box1 div unless you have a reason for needing it.

Comment: @dwreck08 No i want to use box1 that's why i asked.Anyway Thank you and i upvoted your idea.This is nice tricks.I have same two questions for you as i asked to Marc Audet.How long have you been doing designing and which book would you prefer to learn css in depth?